# HTTP Status code to indicate client is out of date

Tags: android, ios, rest, http

The team here are building a mobile (iOS, Android) app to be released into their respective stores shortly. I wanted to introduce the ability to prevent a specific version of the app from logging in (sometime in the future). In fact the first server call should return a specific HTTP code to tell the client app that the request failed (such as log in) but the reason was down to they need to download the newer app from the store. The request header will contain all app specific information so the server will know if it is accepted.

Should it return `401 Unauthorized` or `403 Forbidden` and in the body have a specific information indicating the reason for failure, or could a specific http code be used? We want a specific message to be displayed rather than a generic one so it would need to map correctly to the data returned.

Comment: Why not create a separate endpoint that the app makes a request against to see if the version of the app is supported? You can then have the response body be whatever you want. Nearly all apps I have worked on went this route and has worked out well.

Comment: That is a better long term solution, but for version 1 we don't have the ability to put this in place becuase of time. For now the server won't change but the app could display the version upgrade message when it is implemented on the server. version 2 will probably have a separate endpoint

Answer (score 0):

IMO neither 401 nor 403 is appropriate, your app does have access and is authorized to access your server and you can successfully communicate with it. If it wasn't authorized or can't access the server for example then how can the server even determine the app version needs to upgrade?

I would return a regular http success to indicate you DID communicate with your server, and your server then went on to determine the version of your app and respond to that.

You could add a message in the http body but its arguably easier to add a custom field to the http response header then there is no need for it to contain a body. And obtaining the http header field in the app is straightforward.

And the message you are talking about being displayed should be coming from your app once your app has parsed the http response header - your question seems to be implying you think or expect the OS could or should be displaying this message based on the http status code. It shouldn't, it should be your app doing so.

Comment: Thanks... The message displayed will be displayed by the app and not by the OS, it just needs to know what the message should be.